# Calculate object position (physics) in java

Tags: java, physics

i have task to write program to calculate object position in java, but im not expert to physics problems, i just have this formula :

[image: formula to calculated distance].

the program will need input and then calculate last position (y axis or even both, with x axis) of object after *t* seconds.

note :the program need input of initial position of object and how long the object to move freely.

at least someone give me clue to this problem, because im not good with physic.

Comment: You don't explain the formula or show code/any attempt. We won't do your homework, so try at least sth. and give us more informations.

Comment: Im just expect to get algorithm, not even single code or even complete code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula says that the position of the object `d` is equal to it's initial speed `v` multiplied by time `t` and `1/2` times the acceleration `a` times the square of the time `t`.

Now you just have to insert values for the given variables speed `v`, time `t`, acceleration `a`.

This calculation has to be done for each axis. If you work in 2-dimensional space, you need a horizontal speed `vx`, a vertical speed `vy`, a horizontal acceleration `ax` and a vertical acceleration `ay`.

The position of the object `(px,py)` is then given by `px=vx*t+ax*t2` and `py=vy*t+ay*t2`

The formula can also be extended to include an initial position by adding `d0`, which is the position at `t=0`. This can be used to calculate the position of the object over and over again by setting the result for the position of the last calculation as the initial position. The time then has to be the difference in time since the last calculation.

Comment: 0.5·a<sub>x</sub>·t² and 0.5·a<sub>y</sub>·t².

Comment: i get it, to calculate last position (d) is d=d0 + vt - (0.5a*t*t), to calculate position x : double dx=posisix +(vx*t); same for y position, thanks.